# axios data differs from request.response

Tags: axios, httpresponse

I'm facing a quite improbable situation. My http request is returning the right data if I read it in the network tab but when trying to retrieve it in the code the data I receive isn't the one I'm expected.

Would you have any lead on understanding what's going on ?
When printing the whole response object, I can see that the response.data doesn't have the same content than the response.request.response
One return an object whose amount is 1450 the other 3750.

Would you have any idea why ?

Screenshot of the console content display different value for data and request.response

[image: 1]

Comment: You are expecting response data in JSON String form. So, use JSON.stringify(response.data) to change JSON to JSON string.

Comment: @ArtBindu thanks for your comment. Actually my problem isn't with the format of the data but with the content itself. I edited my question to clarify

Comment: can you share the source code?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? If yes, could you please, post the answer? So other people could see the solution.